# PHP - How can i echo a specific value from an array?

Tags: php, arrays

I want to echo [id] from my array foreach div,
but when i run my code it only displays ";" in each div.

Here is my PHP:

```
<div class="hidden-navigation" style="display:none;">
    <?php foreach ($searchResultIDs as $key -> $nav) { ?>
        <div class='navigation-item'><?php echo $nav["id"]; ?></div>;
    <?php } ?>
</div>
```

Here is my array:

```
Array
(
[0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [active] => 1
        [id] => 9839
    )

[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [active] => 
        [id] => 66150
    )

[2] => stdClass Object
    (
        [active] => 
        [id] => 66444
    )

[3] => stdClass Object
    (
        [active] => 
        [id] => 67554
    )
)
```

Comment: `foreach ($searchResultIDs as $nav)`

Comment: You can use my function posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72267174/13231904) to turn your `stdClass Object` into an `array` or vice versa for easier manageability.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your array is `stdClass Object`. you should get value like this. and also `->` replace with this `=>`

```
 echo $nav->id;
```

Complete code is:

```
<div class="hidden-navigation" style="display:none;">
    <?php foreach ($searchResultIDs as $nav) { ?>
        <div class='navigation-item'><?php echo $nav->id; ?></div>;
    <?php } ?>
</div>
```

Comment: you should accept correct answer. in future your question is help to other users

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
<?php foreach ($searchResultIDs as $nav) { ?>
     <div class='navigation-item'><?php echo $nav->id; ?></div>;
<?php } ?>
```

`$nav` has`objects` so you can echo by using `->`

Answer (score 0):

The foreach syntax is wrong, it should be `=>` instead of `->`:

```
foreach ($searchResultIDs as $key => $nav)
```

Also `$nav` is an object, so do `$nav->id` instead of `$nav['id']`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try in these different ways

**Step 1:**

```
<div class="hidden-navigation" style="display:none;">
    <?php foreach ($searchResultIDs as  $nav) { ?>
        <div class='navigation-item'><?php echo $nav["id"]; ?></div>;
    <?php } ?>
</div>
```

**Step 2:**

```
<div class="hidden-navigation" style="display:none;">
    <?php foreach ($searchResultIDs as $key => $nav) { ?>
        <div class='navigation-item'><?php echo $nav->id; ?></div>;
    <?php } ?>
</div>
```